# Change colors of android dialog ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, actionbarsherlock

Hello I am using actionbarsherlock in my application I have styled it, however when I want to make a dialog it is looking like this http://tinypic.com/r/11ha0w2/6 so i want to change all of that light blue to a other color. Does someone know and maybe give me an example of how to achieve this?

How to style a Dialog?